# Process status in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

In my logcat, the process stops and starts. There are no problems with the application running in the emulator. Is this normal? Or did I mess up something in the code? I don't even know what to cling to.

```
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (20867) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (21103) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (21103) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (21629) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (21629) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (22228) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (22228) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (22626) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (22626) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (24258) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (24258) for package sicilla.VXR ----------------------------
```

I have no idea why this is happening. The app has a foreground service, if that's important